# Creating table in Wicket

Tags: html, apache, wicket, html-table

I am trying to display a table using Wicket. I am using `Panel` to create the table and `PropertyColumns` to add the columns.

How do I group few of the columns into one single column.

Comment: All I want to do is to have a common header for a group of columns.

Comment: Maybe try adding the end state of the HTML that you are trying to render because it is not really clear what you are trying to do accomplish

Comment: Ahh!I tried putting the image of table i want but my "reputation points stops me from doing that.

let me explain in little more detail what I am trying.
My table has 2 columns, Product and Unit tests.
I want to divide Unit Tests column in two parts, Passed and Failed.

I am able to create a table with 2 columns. I am generating the columns as follow

List<IColumn> columnList = new ArrayList();
columnList.add(new PropertyColumn<Data>(new Model("Product"), "productName", "productName");
columnList.add(new PropertyColumn<Data>(new Model("Unit Test"), null, null);

Comment: Put that code into to question.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you are using a [`DataTable`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/extensions/markup/html/repeater/data/table/DataTable.html) or descendant. For your case i would use a [`ListView`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/list/ListView.html) where you can easier control the output HTML.

In HTML:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Product</th>
      <th colspan="2">Unit tests</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Passed</th>
      <th>Failed</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr wicket:id="listView">
      <td wicket:id="productComponent">Product</td>
      <td wicket:id="passedComponent">PassedColumn</td>
      <td wicket:id="failedComponent">FailedColumn</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

In Java:

```
 add(new ListView<SomeDetails>("listView", listData)
 {
        public void populateItem(final ListItem<SomeDetails> item)
        {
                final SomeDetails data= item.getModelObject();
                item.add(new Label("productComponent", data.getProduct()));
                item.add(new Label("passedComponent", data.getPassed()));
                item.add(new Label("failedComponent", !data.getPassed()));
        }
 });
```

Comment: I think your wicket id should be on the tr elements not the tbody element.

Comment: Pappin is right. If the id is on the tbody tag, it will get repeated with every SomeDetails item.